# FaceTime Photos must be enabled on both devices to use this feature

Tags: settings, facetime, privacy

When I'm on a FaceTime video call, there's a camera button.

When I press the FaceTime camera button to take a photo, I get the message:

> FaceTime Photos must be enabled on both devices to use this feature.

What is FaceTime Photos? How can I enable this feature?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This camera button is the **FaceTime Live Photos** feature.

> When you’re on a FaceTime video call with one or more people, you can take a Live Photo to capture a moment from the call. Both of you receive a notification that the photo was taken, and the Live Photo goes right into your Photos library.
>
> The other person on the call **may need to set their FaceTime preferences to allow a Live Photo before you can take one.**

iOS > Settings > FaceTime > FaceTime Live Photos

In addition to the Settings toggle, there is a **minimum OS requirement**. I got the same error message when FaceTiming with an older macOS computer.

> Note: To capture a Live Photo in a one-on-one call, both you and the other person on the call must be using the **latest version of either macOS 10.13.6 or macOS Mojave 10.14.4 or later, iOS 12.1.4 or later, or iPadOS**. To capture a Live Photo of a person in a group call, both you and the other person on the call must be using macOS Catalina or later, iOS 13 or later, or iPadOS.
>
> https://support.apple.com/guide/facetime/take-a-live-photo-fctm0ce5cbbe/mac